# Geodesic on Finsler surface

Tags: finsler-geometry

Consider $S$ which is a two-dimensional surface with an induced
metric from a normed space $(\mathbb{R}^3,\|\ \|)$. When $c$ is a
curve of unit speed $c : [0,l]\rightarrow S$, i.e. $\| c'(t)\|=1$,
s.t. $c(0)=p,\ c(l)=q$, then consider a variation $c :
[-\delta,\delta ]\times [0,l]\rightarrow
 S$ with $c(s,0)=p,\ c(s,0)=q$. Then find a sufficient condition
 s.t. ${\rm length}\ c(0,\ )$ is minimizing in this variation.

Reference : Intrinsic geometry of surfaces in normed spaces - Burago
and Ivanov

Answer (score 0):

Define $$ T : D=[-\delta,\delta ]\times [0,l]\rightarrow
 S,\ T(s,a)=c_t(s,a)$$

When $\| T\|\geq 1$, then $T(D)$ is tangent to $\| \ \|$-unit sphere along $T(c_t(0,a))$ and $T(D)$
 is outside.